# Convert implicit varchar max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

When I use the CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), Field) to extract the first 200 characters of a varchar(max) field, SQL show me a warning on the select operator on the execution plan as in the below image

[image]
This is the simple query I used:

```
select top ? convert(varchar(200),Column1) from Object1
```

I try to compare 3 select:

1. the first one with convert
   [image]
2. the second with the left function
   [image]
3. the last without any trasformation.
   [image]

In terms of granted memory the result is the same and in the plan I can see that the compute scalar  operator reduce the size of data after its execution. So, why the warning with convert?

Comment: What is the *actual* query? Can you also [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) please?

Comment: Also, why not use `LEFT` instead of `CONVERT`?

Comment: When you change a datatype (explicitly or implicitly) in a `join` or `where` clause (and that includes length of the datatype), you *always* get this cardinality warning.

Comment: Ignore it, "may affect cardinality estimate" <> "will affect cardinality estimate"

Comment: I upgrade with the simple statement. I would use left but the behavior of the convert is better for me because after the compute scalar the data size was reduced.